# Ionic build fails at build.xml

Tags: ionic-framework, build-error

Everything been working **superb** on localhost, but then I tried to deploy to my phone:

I added the platform:
    `ionic platform add android` **ok**

Then tried to build:

```
ionic build android
```

Got the following error:

TRANSLATION: **"Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado"**  means **"File or directory not found"**, but they do, I can't count how many times I checked.

[image]

I Created a brand new app and tried to build. Same error.

Can you help me please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This seem to be related to permission. Make sure you have an execute permission on the file it's trying to access/ run.